# Redirect all websites of a subdirectory to one single website (actually two, one for each language)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

im trying to do the following: I have a website with an English version and a German version. Now I'm trying to redirect the English visitors to an English page and the German visitors to the German page.

The URLs of the English version look like this: example.com/en/some-page
The URLs of the German version look like this: example.com/some-page

I'm trying to get a temporary redirection (302?) for all my pages, so every English page (URLs starting with example.com/en/) should be redirected to example.com/en/english-announcement and all German pages (URLs starting with example.com) should be redirected to example.com/german-announcement. The visitors should not be able to access any other page than either example.com/german-announcement or example.com/en/english-announcement.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that it is a wordpress page, so there is a default .htaccess file that looks like this:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

If you could tell me how to do this I'll be eternally grateful.